# cannot compile java files using cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin, classpath

I am trying to compile some files using cygwin shell.

java file that I am trying to compile is C:\Users\Programs\x.java

For windows command prompt

> C:\Users\Programs>javac x.java

No errors.

For Cygwin shell

> $ javac /cygdrive/c/Users/Programs/x.java

Error:

> javac: file not found: \cygdrive\c\Users\Programs\x.java

Why do I get an error in cygwin shell though it runs in windows command prompt

Comment: Can you access the folder `/cygdrive/c/Users/Programs/` through Cygwin?

Comment: guess i can, when i do a tab from /cygdrive/c/Users/Programs  x.java is showing up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`javac` is Windows application. It has no clue about `/cygdrive`. Always keep it in mind and pass valid Windows paths.

So use `javac 'c:/Users/Programs/x.java'` or `javac c\:/Users/Programs/x.java`
Also, as in most Unix shells \ must be escaped if you need to use it.

Comment: Or even `javac 'c:\Users\Programs\x.java'` (using regular Windows back-slashes protected by bash single-quotes)

Comment: in this `javac c\:/Users/Programs/x.java` why is the `\\` used

Comment: @vjk you have to escape unquoted `:` that's what `\` is for and that's why you can't use it directly but only in single quotes.

Comment: @Alex Gitelman: You don't need to escape `:` as bash does not treat it as a special character when used as part of a file name like this.  It is just that some programs such as scp, rsync, tar treat the stuff before `:` as a host-name but bash doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that "cygdrive" is a pseudo-device that is implemented in a Cygwin-specific library.  If the executable you are running has not been linked against that library (and the Oracle Java executables have not!) it won't correctly resolve the "/cygdrive" path component.